# matrix multiplying between files in python

Tags: python, file, matrix

```
import linecache

fileA = open('matrixA.txt', 'r' )

line2 = linecache.getline('matrixA.txt', 2)
line3 = linecache.getline('matrixA.txt', 3)
line4 = linecache.getline('matrixA.txt', 4)

two = line2.split()
list2 = list(map(int, two))

three = line3.split()
list3 = list(map(int,three))

four = line4.split()
list4 = list(map(int, four))

listA = [list2]+[list3]+[list4]
print (listA)

fileB = open('matrixB.txt', 'r')

Bline2 = linecache.getline('matrixB.txt', 2)
Bline3 = linecache.getline('matrixB.txt', 3)
Bline4 = linecache.getline('matrixB.txt', 4)

btwo = Bline2.split()
blist2 = list(map(int, btwo))

bthree = Bline3.split()
blist3 = list(map(int,bthree))

bfour = Bline4.split()
blist4 = list(map(int, bfour))

listB = [blist2] + [blist3] + [blist4]
print (listB)

q = listA[0] #
h = listB[0] #This part dosn't work 
aq = q*h     #
print(aq)    #

//for i in range(listA):
```

So I have this code so far from my 2 files file A prints as:

> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]

And file B prints as:

> [[3, 3, 9], [7, 4, 8], [4, 20, 30]]

How would I get these two matrices to multiply, I know you would need positions but I don't know how to do the loop.

Comment: if you want to do matrix multiplication A to B, you'll get an error, the shape is mismatch. Number of column in A should be same with number of row in B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have loaded your *.txt data correctly (you start to read your data from the second line), then to multiply it the simple one is by converting it to numpy array and use `np.dot`.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.asarray(listA)
B = np.asarray(listB)
res = np.dot(B,A)
print(res)
```

or you can do that without numpy by indexing the list:

```
res = [[0] * len(listA[0]) for _ in range(len(listB))]
for i in range(len(listB)):
    for j in range(len(listA[0])):
        for k in range(len(listA)):
            res[i][j] += listB[i][k]*listA[k][j]
print(res)
```

to make sure your matrix can be multiplied, check the dimension first:

```
if len(listA)==len(listB[0]):
    res = [[0] * len(listA[0]) for _ in range(len(listB))]
    for i in range(len(listB)):
        for j in range(len(listA[0])):
            for k in range(len(listA)):
                res[i][j] += listB[i][k]*listA[k][j]
    print(res)
else:
    print("ERROR! Size Mismatch")
```